# MariaDB 10.2: Why does Count(*) work, but not Count(t.*)

Tags: syntax, mariadb-10.2

I have a table containing transaction details which I am importing from several vendor-provided daily reports.. I want to be sure that I am not skipping any of the files (one file per day) as I do this process..

So I wanted to query the database to find the number of distinct dates it found in the result set.

At first I tried to execute:

```
SELECT COUNT(t.*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT `Date of Survey`  from cc.voc_detail_old) t;
```

But that generates the error "* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax;..."

Changing it to `SELECT Count(*)...` resolves the error and the query functions as expected. Why is it not permissible to use the alias of the derived table in the `Count()` function, but the derived table's alias is required per syntax?

Comment: Also, I do realize I can use `Count(DISTINCT...)` :-)

Comment: And I have also observed that Count(t.*) is not allowed in MS SQL either, so I guess this question isn't specific to MariaDB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MariaDB, the `COUNT()` function expects an expression (that is to say, a single value). For each row where the expression is not NULL, that row will be counted. With `DISTINCT`, as you note, it will only count each distinct non-NULL value once.

`COUNT(*)` is a special case, returning the number of rows in your result set.

<s>`COUNT(t.*)` would only work if there's only one column in table `t`.</s>

Per the OP's testing and my own, `COUNT(t.*)` *does **not** work* even if the table only has one column. See [this dbfiddle.uk link](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=669316b57e84a84abcb8cdf06ec26b0c) to confirm this for yourself.

(Note: You can also see that some other versions of SQL can handle this; if you switch the DB engine to a version of Postgres, the last statement runs successfully, instead of generating an error).